# Colon operator in MATLAB for defining a sequence vector

Tags: matlab, sequence

I have always used colon operator in MATLAB to create a vector in the following way:

```
j:i:k => [j, j + i, j + 2i, ..., j + m * i]
```

but now I need to creat a vector like that:

```
[i, 2i, 4i, 8i, 16i, ... etc]
```

How can I do this using the colon operator?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
(2.^[0:n]) * i
```

Comment: +1 got me by some seconds while posting it. will probably delete then.

Answer (score 1):

You have previously defined an *arithmetic sequence* using some variable `i`, i.e.

```
n = (0:4); 
i = 2;
a = i*n; 

>> i*n

ans =

     0     2     4     6     8
```

What you are trying to define now is a *geometric sequence*, or

```
a = i*2.^n

>> i*2.^n

ans =

     2     4     8    16    32
```

You can also use the above to define complex sequences using the imaginary unit `i` instead

```
a = 1i*2.^n
```